# Living abroad with Mexican insurance and HSA contribution

Tags: irs, hsa, foreign-income, hdhp

I am United States Citizen.

I lived in Mexico all of 2015, I had a high deductible health plan (HDHP) from a Mexican insurance company all of 2015 as well.

My plan meets United States IRS HDHP requirements to make a 2015 HSA contribution, IF I lived in the United States or at least had a United States insurance provider.

I desire to make a 2015 HSA contribution to an American HSA bank account. Though I have no tax liability, other than self employment taxes, that would benefit from the HSA deduction, I still wish to contribute to my HSA account as it is a tax shelter and I can trade stocks and options (treating my HSA like an IRA).

I cannot find anywhere on the IRS website whether I can make an HSA contribution when my high deductible health plan is with a foreign insurance company.This Mexican insurance company will not provide proof of my HDHP insurance, either 1099-HC, my #SS or otherwise, to the IRS, as is required by United States insurance companies.

Comment: Is the HSA account already established?

Comment: Yes the HSA account is already established, but I am not sure that matters...

Comment: And the HSA account is with american HSA Bank

Comment: Is your goal to make 2015 contributions in to the HSA account?

Comment: Are you paying US taxes for 2015? If not, why would you want to contribute to an HSA?

Comment: @BenMiller An HSA is a tax sheltered account, it can be used for trading stocks and buying options, you can "power up" an HSA into an IRA

Comment: @quid Hi quid, yes I want to make a 2015 contribution

Comment: @BrianOgden Are you a U.S. citizen?  Did you file a tax return (or are you planning on filing a tax return) for 2015?

Comment: @BenMiller yes I am a U.S. citizen, and I am filling a 2015 tax return